# How can i escape "?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, html-agility-pack

```
if (richTextBox1.Lines[i].StartsWith(@"<a href=""") ||
     richTextBox1.Lines[i].EndsWith(@""""))
```

The StartsWith should be `<a href="`
The EndsWith should be one single `"`

But the way it is now i'm getting no results.

Input for example:

```
<a href="/setprefs?suggon=2&amp;prev=https://www.test.com/search?q%3D%2Band%2B%26espv%3D2%26biw%3D960%26bih%3D489%26source%3Dlnms%26tbm%3Disch%26sa%3DX%26ei%3DYrxxVb-hJqac7gba0YOgDQ%26ved%3D0CAYQ_AUoAQ&amp;sig=0_seDQVVTDQQx1hvN3BRktZNFc9Ew%3D" style="left:-1000em;position:absolute">Screen-reader users, click here to turn off ggg Instant.</a>
```

I need to get this part:

```
/setprefs?suggon=2&amp;prev=https://www.test.com/search?q%3D%2Band%2B%26espv%3D2%26biw%3D960%26bih%3D489%26source%3Dlnms%26tbm%3Disch%26sa%3DX%26ei%3DYrxxVb-hJqac7gba0YOgDQ%26ved%3D0CAYQ_AUoAQ&amp;sig=0_seDQVVTDQQx1hvN3BRktZNFc9Ew%3D
```

The part between the

I also tried to use htmlagilitypack:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();

                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.test.com");                       

                        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                        {
                            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);

                                if (!newHtmls.Contains(hrefValue) && hrefValue.Contains("images"))
                                    newHtmls.Add(hrefValue);
                        }
```

But this gave me only 1 link.
When i browse and see the page view-source and i make search and filter with the word image or images im getting over 350 results.

I tried also this solution:

```
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

But it didnt give me the results i needed.

Forgot to mention that the view-source of the page content i copied it to richTextBox1 window and then i'm reading line by line the text from the richTextBox1 so maybe that's why i'm not getting the results as i need ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (richTextBox1.Lines[i].StartsWith("<a href=\"") &&
                        richTextBox1.Lines[i].EndsWith("\""))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Maybe the view-source content as it's in the browser(chrome) is not the same as in the richTextbox1. And maybe i should not read it line by line from the richTextBox1 maybe to read the whole text from the richTextBox1 first ?

Comment: that should be it...

Comment: please show a input value.

Comment: Wouldn't it end with `">`? As Daniel said, need the input value(s). BTW, you should really be looking at HtmlAgilityPack for this kind of thing.

Comment: Also it should be && and not || if you need that both expressions are true.

Comment: The " is escaped with and \ so: .StartsWith("<a href=\"") || .EndsWith("\"")

Comment: `(@"<a href=""")` => `<a href""` and you need this `<href="` so what you should do is remove extra`"`.

Comment: @Luc: Not for [strings literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (those starting with `@`).

Comment: He doesn't need string literals. It was probably an attemtt to getting this to work. That is why I didn't add the @ to my comment

Comment: Luc tried your solution but i forgot to mention i'm reading the lines one by one from a rcihTextBox1.Text so maybe that's why i'm getting 0 results when using your soltuion ? updated my question with how i'm reading it from the richTextBox1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input, `EndsWith` isn't doing to help (as your input actually ends with `</a>`. Your next-best option would be to store the location (position) of `href="`, then look for the next occurrence of a `"` beginning at your stored location. e.g.

```
var input = @"<a href=""/setprefs?suggon=2&amp;prev=https://www.test.com/search?q%3D%2Band%2B%26espv%3D2%26biw%3D960%26bih%3D489%26source%3Dlnms%26tbm%3Disch%26sa%3DX%26ei%3DYrxxVb-hJqac7gba0YOgDQ%26ved%3D0CAYQ_AUoAQ&amp;sig=0_seDQVVTDQQx1hvN3BRktZNFc9Ew%3D"" style=""left:-1000em;position:absolute"">Screen-reader users, click here to turn off ggg Instant.</a>";

var needle = @"href=""";
var start = input.IndexOf(needle);
if (start != -1)
{
    start += needle.Length;
    var end = input.IndexOf(@"""", start);

    // final result:
    var href = input.Substring(start, end - start).Dump();
}
```

Better than that would be to use an actual HTML parser (might I recommend HtmlAgilityPack?).